# Do I need any kind of java installation on a webserver that hosts java applets?

Tags: applet, webserver, java

A webserver hosting java applets doesn't necessarily need java installed on it, right?
It's the clients computer that views the applets that needs a java jre installation or similar?
Or do I get this wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to have Java installed or running on the server, as long as your HTML pages and the jar and class files are available via the web server, it's the client that'll use them.

Answer (score 1):

No, as long a the applets are compiled somewhere else